# Setup Docker on Windows 10 Enterprise

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I have windows 10 Enterprise, 64-bit, build: Version 10.0.17763 Build 17763. Installed Oracle VM VirtualBox.

Downloaded latest Docker for Windows: https://hub.docker.com/?overlay=onboarding and getting this error:

[image]

**Take 2**: Removed newest version and installed version 2.0.0.1: https://chocolatey.org/packages/docker-desktop/2.0.0.2

now it's opening but I get the following:

> Unable to check availability for Windows feature *Hyper-V*: The
>   running command stopped because the preference variable
>   "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: The
>   specified module 'Dism' was not loaded because no valid module file
>   was found in any module directory.    at
>   Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.Send(String action, Object[]
>   parameters) in
>   C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeClient.cs:line
>   36    at Docker.Actions.DoStart(SynchronizationContext syncCtx,
>   Boolean showWelcomeWindow, Boolean executeAfterStartCleanup) in
>   C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Windows\Actions.cs:line
>   92    at Docker.Actions.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.b__0() in
>   C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Windows\Actions.cs:line
>   74    at Docker.WPF.TaskQueue.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<.ctor>b__1() in
>   C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.WPF\TaskQueue.cs:line 59
>   [image]

When I run the following command from CMD I get:
[image]

**Take 3:**
Updated to latest version of Docker for Windows and I get this:
[image]

> Unable to stop - The running command stopped because the preference
>   variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop:
>   The specified module 'Hyper-V' was not loaded because no valid module
>   file was found in any module directory.

How does one setup Docker for windows?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This fixed it for me:

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/65#issuecomment-243458778

- enable Hyper-V (in PowerShell): `DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V`
- restart Windows Services => Docker Desktop Service (per link above)

Answer (score 0):

Even on supported Windows versions you still need to enable Hyper-v with DISM. There's instructions from Microsoft here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v#enable-hyper-v-with-cmd-and-dism

Comment: didn't help. ran DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V, and Hyper-V is enabled. restarted. Still the same error